# css moving a border inside a table cell

Tags: css, border

I have table cells where I've set various images as the border with no margin around the cell. Is there a way to then put a coloured border inside the images, pushing the border into the cell rather than right at the edges?

Comment: Without any code it's going to be difficult to help you, could you set a jsfiddle with your problem?

Answer (score 8):

If you can use CSS3, just look towards `outline` property.
This example makes 2px blue border inside table cell.

CSS:

```
td.bordred {
    outline: solid 2px #377bb5;
    outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried playing with `border-style: inset;`?

Comment: I'll try that. I think I've also found another way to do it: wrap the cell content in another div and set a margin, border, and padding on that.

Comment: That might work out, too. I might suggest seeking out CSS-only alternatives to keep your website as semantic as possible (which is to say, keeping structural elements like divs as structural devices, rather than using them to add styling to your page). Either way would probably be fine, though :)

Comment: `border-style: inset;` just describes a 3D effect for drawing the border. It doesn't seem to have any effect on where the border goes.